# paypal not showing on woocommerce payments

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

[image]
Had install a fresh wordpress installation on localhost, and after install woocommerce plugin, the paypal default - payment isnt there on woocommerce tab "payments".  On the live website paypal continues working just fine.  Do I need a plugin now, anyone knows something about it

Comment: It should be enabled as long as [your store's currency is supported by PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/reference/paypal-supported-currencies/). If that's not it there's probably somewhere it's enabled or disabled in the admin site.

Comment: I have € (euro) as currency. I cant find anyone with this error as well. Im trying to find now where at database we can see the payment methods active. maybe I can change that over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal standard is now hidden for new installs, possible to read about it in https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/07/12/developer-advisory-paypal-standard-will-be-hidden-on-new-installs/

for those who want to use it copy paste this code on functions.php

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_should_load_paypal_standard', '__return_true' );
```

Since july 2021 woocommerce recommends users to use the recommended [PayPal](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/) extension instead